# How to do a alternate color using conditional formating in google sheet with certain condtion

Tags: google-sheets, filter, match, google-sheets-formula

I want to alternate color every time there is column B is contain text, is it possible to do it using conditional formatting?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if B column values are unique you can do:

```
=ISODD(COUNTUNIQUE(B$1:B1))*(A1<>"")
```

---

```
=ISEVEN(COUNTUNIQUE(B$1:B1))*(A1<>"")
```

[image: 0]

---

if B column values are same as in your example:

```
=ISODD(MATCH(B$1, FILTER(B$1:B1, B$1:B1<>"")))*(A1<>"")
```

---

```
=ISEVEN(MATCH(B$1, FILTER(B$1:B1, B$1:B1<>"")))*(A1<>"")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: thanks for the solution, values in column A and B is unique. your solution can do the alternate color for column B, but when i extend the coloring from column A to B, it not working anymore. is it possible to extend the color from column A to B?

Comment: yes, that is possible. all you need to do is change apply range from B:B to A:B and the in front of every Column reference in formula you put $ to lock it. so for example 4th formula: `=ISEVEN(MATCH($B$1, FILTER($B$1:$B1, $B$1:$B1<>"")))*($A1<>"")` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU964.png